# Getting active background color using useRef

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

Given the css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.App:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

and jsx code

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const r = useRef();
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(r.current.style.backgroundColor);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App" ref={r} onClick={handleClick}>
      something
    </div>
  );
}
```

See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-water-6gw5iq?file=/src/App.js)
I want to get the active background color of div (which is red). But the code give me nothing. What's the right way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.style` only tells you the inline style on the element, and this div has no inline style. If you want to know the style that results when combining inline style and css selectors, you need [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
const handleClick = () => {
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(r.current).backgroundColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`el.style.X` is not working correctly. Insteadof this use [window.getComputedStyle(el)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and u can get full list of styles. As a [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-river-gbmqgn) u can see it.